# How do I redirect from an exact url in golang?

Tags: url, redirect, go, webserver

Whenever a request is made from localhost:9000/ I want to redirect the user to localhost:9000/#/trade/gem/GEM . The problem I am getting is that I get infinite redirects because "/" preceeds every url. How do I make it so that the user is only redirected if they visit the exact url of localhost:9000/ ? My code is below:

```
var newUrl string = "/#/trade/gem/GEM"

func handleRedirect(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    http.Redirect(rw, req, newUrl, http.StatusSeeOther)
}

func main() {
    http.Handle("/#/trade/", fs)
    http.HandleFunc("/", handleRedirect) //This is the exact url I want to redirect from
    http.ListenAndServe(":9000", nil)
}
```

Comment: The fragment (everything after the `#`) is not transmitted to the server. You'll have pick a different approach.

Comment: What does this have to do with my question? I am only interested in redirecting the exact url of "localhost:9000/". Whether or not I use a hash in the url to redirect to shouldn't make a difference should it?

Comment: @cookiekid, you cannot tell the difference between `/` and `/#/trade/gem/GEM` on the server; they both look like `/`, hence the redirect loop. The fragment is for client-side use only (i.e. JavaScript).

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks. So I have to do the redirect on the frontend then. I think React Router has a tool for that anyway.

Answer (score 1):

When the `/` is registered then all the url will redirect to this until the other pattern is not registered.To solve this and handling only specific patterns you can write a custom handler and you can implement a logic where it redirects to the specific url whenever the `localhost:9000/` is opened.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

type Handler struct{}

var NewUrl string = "/trade/gem/GEM"

func (h *Handler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    uri := r.URL.Path
    if uri == "/" {
        http.Redirect(w, r, NewUrl, http.StatusSeeOther)
    }
    fmt.Fprintf(w, uri)
    return
}

func main() {
    handler := new(Handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":9000", handler)
}
```

For more details check [http.handler](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Handler)

***Note:*** You can not use `#` in the uri.